# Apparent and real depth object in water

Tags: homework-and-exercises, optics, refraction

[image]

Did I get my formula right? Seems like the correct answer is $d_o = 1.33 \times d_i$ but I thought the formula I should use is $d_i = - \frac{n_2}{n_1} d_o$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

we have the formula

n = real depth/apparent depth

so, real depth = n * apparent depth
               = 1.33 * o.4
               = 0.532
so right ans may be D

here n is refractive index of water with respect to air

Comment: Hmm ... maybe I missed out this formula? But is the formula I have correct? If so why cant I get the right answer? Any ideas?

Comment: Also if we had such a formula, then the other n must be vacuum?

Comment: Oh I got it ... $n_2$ is on the other side of the object!

Comment: Narendra, please keep in mind for the future that our [homework policy](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/714) prohibits posting complete answers to homework questions. Ordinarily this would be temporarily deleted, but in this case it's already been seen so there would be little point. Just please don't post such answers in the future.